# Integration containing Greatest integer function.

Tags: integration

I am trying to integrate $$ \int_{-1}^{2}|x[x]|dx$$ where [x] denotes greatest integer function. I don't know how to approach this problem. Please help.

Comment: Break down your interval of integration to parts where the greatest integer function is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$[x]=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}-1& x\in[-1,0)\\0& x\in[0,1)\\1& x\in[1,2)\end{array}\right.$$

Hence $$\int_{-1}^2|x[x]|dx=\int_{-1}^0|-x|dx+\int_1^2|x|dx=-\int_{-1}^0xdx+\int_1^2xdx=-\left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{-1}^0+\left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{1}^2=2$$

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Just split it to $3$ intervals with length $1$ separately as the floor function would take the same value.

Alternatively,

[image]

Sketch the picture and you just have to compute the area under the graph.